# Session not working as it has to be, auto session lost or content loss upon refresh page

Tags: php, session

I am new is PHP, doing my final year project in Student Result Online System.

In my system, I have an error in session, Once the user/student logs in using their user name and password, the dashboard displays his details properly.

But, as soon as the page reloads or you click to view other contents or just simply click on the student's tool bar within dashboard, the page loses all of its relevant contents and becomes idle or blank.

**I want to prevent auto session destroy or loss while the user remains on the same page until he/she logs-out**. any help would be grateful. Interesting thing is that, this codes works really well in Localhost (Wamp Server), but it loses its session in Online (cpanel).

My codes pages are: 
**login.php**

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    session_start();
    $student_no = $_POST['student_no'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_no='$student_no' AND    password='$password' and status = 'active' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if( $num_row > 0 ) {
        header('location:dasboard.php');
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['student_id'];
    }
    elae{
         header('location:access_denied.php');
    }
}
?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {
   header("location: index.php");
   exit();
}
$session_id=$_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

**dasboard.php**

```
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
<?php 
    $query=mysql_query("select * from students where student_id='$session_id'")or   die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$year_level = $row['year_level'];
$term = $row['term'];
$status = $row['student_status'];
$school_year = $row['year_level'];?>
<div class="container">
<div class="margin-top">
<div class="row">
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
<div class="span12">
<div class="grade">
<?php include('grade_option.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span2">
<?php include('user_sidebar.php'); ?>
</div>
<div class="span10">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table  table-bordered" id="example"> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100">Code</th>
<th  width="300">Subject</th>
<th  width="50">Units</th> 
 <th>Gen Ave.</th>
<th>Term</th>
 <th>Year Level</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  $user_query=mysql_query("select * from grade where student_id = '$session_id' and school_year = '$year_level'
                              and semester = '$term'
                              ")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
                                $id=$row['grade_id'];
$remarks = $row['remarks'];
$subject_id = $row['subject_id'];
$subject_query = mysql_query("select * from subject where subject_id = '$subject_id'")or die(mysql_error());
while($subject_row=mysql_fetch_array($subject_query)){
?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $subject_row['code']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $subject_row['title']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $subject_row['unit']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['gen_ave']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['semester']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['school_year']; ?></td>
<?php if ($remarks == 'Very Good'){ ?>
<td><span class="very_good"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td>
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Excellent'){ ?>
<td><span class="Excellent"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td> 
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Satisfactory'){ ?> 
<td><span class="sat"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td> 
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Fair'){ ?>
<td><span class="fair"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td>
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Failed'){ ?>
<td><span class="failed"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td>
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Incomplete'){ ?>
<td><span class="failed"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td>
<?php }else if($remarks == 'Officially Dropped'){ ?>
<td><span class="drop"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td> 
<?php }else if($remarks == 'PASS'){ ?>
<td><span class="Excellent"><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></span></td>
<?php }else if ($remarks == ''){ ?> 
<td><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php }} ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php include('units_table.php'); ?>
<?php include('gwa_table.php'); ?>
<?php include('cwa_table.php'); ?>
</div>
<?php include('grading_system.php') ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: please update the login.php script in your question with the latest code that you have. it is confusing when trying to work out where the errors are. Also, include a 'var_dump($_SESSION, $session_id); at the end of 'session.php' and before the $query in header.php, btw, it would be easier for yourself if you called it '$_SESSION['student_id']' as there is less confusion later.

Comment: Can you check, I have found the problem within this code from dasboard.php page: 
<?php
$query=mysql_query("select * from students where student_id='$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$year_level = $row['year_level'];
$term = $row['term'];
$status = $row['student_status'];
$school_year = $row['year_level'];
 ?>
I think, I have to setup cookies to store session somewhere in dasboard.php, But I have no idea regarding. If you can, would be greatful. If i get your email, I can send you link to see what is exact error?!

Comment: an email address that i can be contacted on can be found here [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1taYrDSA). It is very public but any email in there is removed every few hours.

Comment: I have sent you an email in your mail, that you have given to me. Regards

Comment: @Ryan Vincent,
I did var_dump($_SESSION, $session_id); at the end of 'session.php' and before the $query in dasboard.php as you said.

It display all data with this message prints on the page:

array(4) { ["is"]=> &NULL ["log"]=> &array(2) { ["login"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(5) "sunil" } ["image"]=> &string(54) "uploads/01df098be1598e67c4e4f2295d4bdcd825b20f35f5.jpg" ["id"]=> &string(3) "687" } string(3) "687"

Comment: My code works everything well, only problem is in refresh page. 
Once I refresh or reload page, it looses its all data.(which previously pulled from Database ) and remain page empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your following code:

```
if( $num_row > 0 ) {
    header('location:dasboard.php');
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['student_id'];
}
```

You do

```
header('location:dasboard.php');
```

Before you set the session:

```
$_SESSION['id']=$row['student_id'];
```

Meaning you redirect first, and session is NEVER set.

[By the way `header.php`, includes `header.php`?](http://inception.davepedu.com/)

And

```
elae{
     header('location:access_denied.php');
}
```

Should be `else` of course.

Comment: Mr. Tim Dev, Thank you for your reply, but Still have same problem, your advice not solving my problem. I mentioned priviously, My code works well for first login. The only problem is in the reload or refresh dasboard.php pag. (If I refresh page, or click other link inside this page, the data will lost and remain blank with static values). May be I didn't understand your solution properly. You told me to correct session.php page of Login.php page? I did both, but not solved. 
Ya, I never includes header.php in header.php. 
Ya, also I correct else. 
I'v my final presentation day after tomorrow.

Comment: Dear @Tim Dev, thank you so much for your continue help for my problem. 
I did, as you have suggested, but not working at all. I think, there is something error in dasboard.php code. Because, on login, it take me to the dashboard.php page showing all the related contents from database, but as soon as, when i click any link on dashboard or refresh or reload dashboard.php page, it loss all its contents. I hope you understand my problem is. Else, I can explain more. Regards

Comment: One more clue, i have found right now. Admin can add new student.
After that, the admin will add marks subject wise to that particular student. Till no record inserts for that student ( his dasboard.php (after login), shows his personal detail), dasboard.php display his infomation, but after inserted subject and marks obtained by him/her(by admin), in this case , after first login, he/she get all detail information in dasboard.php, but in refresh or reload or click any link on dasboard.php, all the information gone/ lost/ losses. So, painful for me to sort-out this error.